# Removing Spring.Cache

Tags: caching, spring.net

I am trying to clear the cache for my integration testing. I could find "InvalidateCache" attribute in Spring documentation, but i do not want to touch the real function and change the attribute. 
I think I can't use .Net's HttpContext.Cache.Remove since my integration test application is not web application. 
Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think I can't use .Net's
>   HttpContext.Cache.Remove since my
>   integration test application is not
>   web application.

Why don't you create an abstraction on it? An ICache interface with a clear method for instance. Then you can use an in memory cache for your integration testing.